# What is the difference between ‘Is it free’ and ‘Is it on the house?’

Tags: word-usage, australian-english

One of my friends said, ‘Is it on the house?’ in Australia, but some felt a little awkward.
Do Australians not usually use the expression, ‘on the house’?

Comment: It is possible that the awkwardness was due to the local standards of etiquette, rather than the language; i.e. it may be that they understood the meaning of the phrase very well, but perceived it as indelicate to explicitly ask whether something is on the house.

Answer (score 8):

"Free" and "on the house" both mean that you don't have to pay, but the inferred meaning is slightly different.

If something is "free" it is *without charge*. For example, you might receive a voucher through the mail that says you are entitled to a free drink if you hand the voucher in at a bar. That drink was *never* going to have a charge attached to it, because it was offered by the bar as a promotion.

When a drink is offered "on the house", the inference is that the "house" or establishment is *buying the drink for you*. Similarly, if you were drinking with a friend and he/she said "these are *on me*" it would mean that they are picking up the bill.

True, the outcome of both is essentially the same - a drink that you don't have to pay for. It is also true that some establishments may use the two expressions interchangeably without any attention to the root meanings.

As to whether or not it is a known idiom in Australian English I would have to say *yes* on the basis that it appears in the [script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=crocodile-dundee-ii) for Australian movie *Crocodile Dundee II*:

> -G'day, mate! Bet you've got some stories to tell, eh?
>   -Have I ever, son. Have I ever. But not on a dry throat.
>   -Ida?
>   -**The drinks are on the house.**
>   -That's a first!

Comment: Maybe worth spelling out that only some kinds of establishment are *houses* - if a bookshop gives you a free book, I wouldn't expect them to say it was *on the house*. Chips in a casino could be *on the house*. If something is *on the house* it is normally a consumable of some kind, rather than say a toy or other free gift that you are intended to keep. This may be because establishments that are *houses* tend to provide services rather than selling goods, or it could be a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

It  is an AmE expression, probably not common in Australia;

> From the Oxford English Dictionary: "on the house: at the expense of the tavern, saloon, etc.; also transf. and fig. (orig. U.S.)
>
> 1889 Kansas City (Missouri) Times & Star 30 Nov., The first drink Thursday was 'on the house' in the leading saloons.

(The Phrase Finder)

Answer (score 1):

***Free drinks*** (on the house) and (free drinks are) ***on the house*** in the context of a bar, pub, restaurant, business etc.  mean the same thing

> At the expense of the establishment, as in
>
> - *[This hotel serves an afternoon tea that's on the house.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+house)*
>     This idiom uses house in the sense of "an inn, tavern, or other building serving the public." [Late 1800s]

The expression is very common in the UK, so I would imagine that it's also familiar to Australians; however, in New Zealand and in Australia a term more commonly used to mean “at one's own expense” is ***[shout](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shout)***

> **2.** NZ Australian informal with two objects
>   Treat (someone) to (something, especially a drink)
>
> ‘I'll shout you a beer’
>   ‘He'll happily let you shout him a drink and not return the favour, for example.’
>
> **2.1** no object *Buy a round of drinks*.
>   ‘anyone shooting a hole in one must shout for all players present on the course’
>
> (Oxford Dictionaries)

The awkward atmosphere among the group of friends could have been provoked by the speaker's assumption that he or she didn't have to pay, either the establishment was offering its clients something free of charge or someone in the group had offered to pay/shout for *a round* (of drinks).

References on EL&U
[What terms describe who pays for a meal?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/71180/44619)

[Can I “shout someone out”, or only “give a shout out to” someone (to recognize them)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/127764/44619)

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer; maybe the question has been edited. "shout" in Australia/New Zealand doesn't mean the same as "on the house"?

Comment: @StuartF the OP was asking *Do australians not usually use the expression, ‘on the house’?* which is why I posted the slang meaning of "shout" as a possible answer.

Comment: But *shout* means something different from *on the house*. In AmE, if I say *I'll [stand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand) you a drink*, it means I'm paying for it. If I say *it's on the house*, I'm not paying for it unless I own the bar.

Comment: @Petershore I said very clearlt the Australian expression means at "one's own expense".

Comment: @Mari-LouA: it seems to me that you're saying Australians don't need to use the phrase *on the house* because they have the word *shout*. But I don't think they're interchangeable.

Comment: @PeterShor No, I said that a common Australian term that means the speaker is paying is "shout". When the establishment pays, it is "on the house". But hey, the answer is focuses on the body not on the title. I also cited the dictionary's definition. More than that what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I did some googling as follows:

> pub in australia drinks "on the house"

and I found plenty of "on the house," [for example](https://www.timeout.com/sydney/bars/where-to-play-two-up-on-anzac-day)

> There's live entertainment from noon plus ANZAC biscuits available throughout the day. All service men and women get their first drink on the house.